# Getting 401 error when connecting to the list.asmx web service using JQUERY

Tags: web-services, jquery

I'm attempting to do a pretty straightforward query to the list.asmx web service and I keep getting a 401 error. I've spent a couple of hours attempting to solve it with no luck.

**My jQuery Code:**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://devsp2:3050/_vti_bin/lists.asmx/GetList",
        data: '{"listName":"Site Pages"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    })
```

**Error Details:**

When I execute the code on a test page with a simple button click it prompts me to authenticate. However it asks me to authenticate to the servername.company.com and not the headername I passed.

*Firebug returns:*

{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

*Fiddler returns (Raw):*

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
SPRequestGuid: 9ed17429-0633-4bb8-82dd-fb086b86977f
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.4762
Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 19:43:08 GMT
Content-Length: 16
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

401 UNAUTHORIZED

*soapUI*

When I query the same web service using the same credentials with soapUI, it works great.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Registry Edits

  - BackConnectionHostNames
  - DisableLoopbackCheck
- withCredentials in jQuery

**Updated: Successful Solution**

Thanks to @Mark D Anderson for pointing me in the right direction. The below code works. Credit to Jan Tielen as well (http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx)

```
    var soapEnv =
    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
        <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListCollection xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
            </GetListCollection> \
        </soapenv:Body> \
    </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://devsp2:3050/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
```

Comment: Have you setup an alternate access mapping for devsp2?

Comment: I did not on devsp2:3050 (this is my mysites web application) but I did for devsp2. I changed the public url to http://sprocks.

Comment: Are you able to get there in a browser (The site, not the web service)?

Comment: Yes, I can get to http://devsp2:3050/_vti_bin/lists.asmx and http://devsp2:3050/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=GetList. However, when I go to http://devsp2:3050/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?op=GetList it doesn't allow me to test it even though I'm accessing it from the local server.

Comment: could be some kind of transparent proxy in play as well, or a proxy that is modifying the auth messages. I see the site is using NTLM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the issue is that you are trying to pass JSON data to a SOAP Web Service, which expects XML. Plus, you're not passing in the SOAP envelope which is required. Take a look at [SPServices](http://SPServices.codeplex.com) for examples of how to call the SOAP Web Services.

Comment: This was the issue, thanks for help. I have other SP web services I built that take JSON without any issue so I'm going to compare the two and see what I'm doing differently.